# Setup Nginx Reverse Proxy for Docker app on Domain Subfolder

Tags: docker, nginx, subdomain, nginx-reverse-proxy

**EDIT: The problem is a bug in Plausible, not Nginx. See: https://github.com/plausible/analytics/discussions/1184**

I've been struggling to get my **Nginx Reverse Proxy to work for a Docker app**. Similar questions have been asked but haven't provided the solution for this situation. I've spent hours now trying to get this working.

- I'm trying to self host [Plausible](https://plausible.io/) which runs in a Docker container at `http://localhost:8000`
- Going to `http://server-ip:8000/` works fine

I want to set up a Nginx reverse proxy to provide SSL + and set it up on my domain. The tricky part is that I want to **serve it from a subfolder instead of the root.**

So serving it from `https://app.mydomain.com/plausible` instead of `https://app.mydomain.com/`

**Current Code:**

```
location /plausible {
        rewrite ^/plausible/?(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

### The Problem

- `app.mydomain.com/plausible/` redirects to `app.mydomain.com/login` instead of `app.mydomain.com/plausible/login`.
- If I manually go to `app.mydomain.com/plausible/login` I can see the form field but all the styling and scripts are broken. They try to load from `app.mydomain.com/stylesheet.css` instead of `app.mydomain.com/plausible/stylesheet.css`

**So I believe the Docker app expects to be on the root URL. So Nginx should rewrite the requests to include the subfolder in some way?** I just can't figure out how to do it.

**What I've tried:**

- Trailing slash, no trailing slash
- Just proxy_pass
- All kinds of rewrite variations

Anyone who can help me in the right direction? Thank you in advance

Comment: You are going to have to configure plausible and tell it it's on a subdomain so the generated internal URLs point to the right place. I've never used plausible specifically so not sure how you go about doing that, but I've had the same issue with hosting CRA apps and similar on subdomains.

Comment: You need to change your app so that its root become `/plausible/` instead of `/`. Try `BASE_URL` option: https://plausible.io/docs/self-hosting-configuration#server

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Hmm so the problem seems to be the Plausible config... 
I've tried all kinds of BASE_URL options. Maybe my best bet is to contact them. 

BASE_URL= http://localhost:8000/plausible
BASE_URL = http://app.domain.com/plausible/
etc...